# Does Mailkit supports sending anonymous emails?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, mailkit

The Exchange host that I am trying to send emails from does not require authentication. In the past I have successfully achieved this using SmtpClient Class, but as Microsoft is recommending Mailkit, I prefer going for this one.

Does Mailkit always require a username and a password to connect? I have been searching for an answer everywhere but I cannot seem to find one.

This is my code so far:

```
        private void Send(MimeMessage message)
        {
            using (var client = new SmtpClient(new ProtocolLogger(Console.OpenStandardOutput())))
            {
            client.Connect(Host, Port, SecureSocketOptions.None);             

            client.Send(message);
            client.Disconnect(true);
            }
        }
```

And of course I am getting an error: 5.7.1 client was not authenticated

Thank you loads.

Comment: Is that error showing up as an exception?

Comment: `does not require authentication` obviously not. That's a *server error*, not a MailKit error. Exchange *does* require authentication. No sane administrator would disable authentication, allowing spammers to use the mail server. The default is Windows Authentication, which doesn't require any credentials - the connection to the server is made using the executing account's identity

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the server is allowing anonymous email sending

Comment: @mason I think so. I can only see the message on my webpage, as I cannot test the email on the development environment.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How nice it must be to work with competent, security focused IT people! I've encountered my fair share of Exchange servers that have SMTP without authentication needed when accessed internally.

Comment: Why can't you test the email on the local environment? Tools like [Papercut](https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut-SMTP) and [MailHog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog) exist.

Comment: @mason I did not know about Papercut and MailHog. Still a beginner :)). I will look into them. Thank you very much

Comment: @RalucaCristinaDumitru `the server is allowing anonymous email sending` if it did, it wouldn't return an authentication error. You don't need any tools to verify that MailKit works anonymously. It does. Your server doesn't allow anonymous emails though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does Mailkit always require a username and a password to connect? I have been searching for an answer everywhere but I cannot seem to find one.

MailKit does not require authentication - that's up to the server to require it or not.

If a server doesn't require authentication, your code just needs to not call `client.Authenticate()` (or AuthenticateAsync if you are using async code) just like you attempted to do in your example code snippet.

`5.7.1 client was not authenticated` is an error that came from your SMTP server when you attempted to send a message and suggests that your SMTP server is configured to require authentication.

None of the exception messages that MailKit throws start with an error code string (5.7.1 is an SMTP error code), so if an exception is thrown starting with an SMTP error code string, then it means it came from the server.

Comment: Thank you @jstedfast. The server was indeed asking for authentication. All sorted now.